# Possible difference between $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, abelian-groups

Suppose $G$ is a free abelian groups, i.e. a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module; we have a set $S \subset G $ such that $S$ spans $G$.

Can we conclude that the rank of $G$ as a  $\mathbb{Z}$-module is $ \leq |S| $ as in the vector-space case ? Why ?

Comment: Yes. A free $\mathbb{Z}$-module $G$ is contained in a free $\mathbb{Q}$-module $V$, and if $S$ spans $G$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then $S$ spans $V$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-module. You can use the same trick to handle linear independence, but there are still some important differences: a minimal generating set does not have to be linearly independent, since a linear dependence relation does not automatically write one generator in terms of the others.

Comment: @Jack Schmidt: So $S$ contains a subset that is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $V$, but how can we conclude that there is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $G$ ?

Comment: To be clear, I never said anything about bases. However, to answer your question: by assumption $G$ is a free abelian group, i.e. a group that has a basis. That basis need not be contained in $S$, since a minimal generating set does not have to be linearly independent.

Comment: It may help to keep an example in mind: $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $S=\{2,3\}$. $S$ is a minimal generating (spanning) set, but it is not linearly independent. The subset $\{2\}$ is a maximal linearly independent subset that cannot be expanded to a basis (because it is not itself a basis). Same for $\{2\}$. In other words, spanning and linear dependence by themselves work about the same in torsion-free abelian groups, but they are no longer as important, since they no longer "meet" at a basis.

Comment: If this is for a course on infinite abelian groups, then check out the concept of purity and basic subgroups to see how this is fixed. If this an abstract algebra course, just notice things are broken. :-)

Comment: @Jack Schmidt: Ok but I don't understand how can help me the fact that $S$ spans $V$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-module

Comment: Rank(G) = Rank(V) ≤ |S|. A Z-basis of G is a Q-basis of V (not vice verse). A Z-basis of G is Z-lin ind and Z-spanning, so is also Q-LI and Q-spanning. Since S is Q-spanning, it is at least as large as the dimension of V.

Comment: Z-LI = Q-LI. Z-span implies Q-span, but Q-span does not necessarily imply Z-span.

Comment: ok thank you, can I post an answer  ?

Comment: Sure, I'll check it and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $S$ spans $G$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module. $G$ is contained in a free $\mathbb{Q}$-module $V$; $S$ spans $V$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so $\operatorname{rank}(V) \leq |S| $ .

Suppose $B$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $G$; then $B$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow $ $B$ is obviously linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q} $ $\Rightarrow |B|  \leq \operatorname{rank}(V) \leq |S| $

Observe that $|B|$ is well-defined because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a commutative ring.

Comment: Looks good. Just to make sure you know: $|B|$ is well-defined for commutative rings (and lots of noncomm rings too, but not all). PID makes bases work better, but their constant cardinality is a general commutative thing.

Answer (score 4):

There are also many differences between vector spaces and $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Every vector space has a basis, but not every $\mathbb{Z}$-module. For example, any finite abelian group is not a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Q}$ is not free.
Furthermore a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module may have a linear independent set which cannot be extended to a basis. It also may have a subset $S$ which spans it, but does not contain a basis.